# Split VueJs Components

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-router

I would like to split my VueJs components into different files like this:

```
-file.vue
-file.html
-file.ts
-file.css
```

```
///AppBar.vue
<template src="./AppBar.html"></template>
<script lang="ts" src="./AppBar.js"></script>
```

```
///AppBar.html
<div>
    <v-app-bar
      color="#007dbc"
      style="z-index: 1000"
    >
    <v-img
        class="mx-2"
        src="@/assets/dkt_logo.png"
        max-height="40"
        max-width="150"
        contain
      ></v-img>
      <v-toolbar-title style="color: white; font-size: 27px">PCB Sizing</v-toolbar-title>

      <v-spacer></v-spacer>

      <v-btn icon @click="logout" v-if="isLogin">
        <v-icon style="color: white">mdi-logout-variant</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-app-bar>
  </div>
```

```
///AppBar.ts
import Vue from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({
    name : "AppBar",
    data: () => ({
        
    }),
    methods: {
        logout(){
            this.$router.push('/')
        }
    },
    computed:{
        isLogin(){
            return !['Login'].includes(this.$route.name)
        }
    }
})
```

I already tried that but when I run my serve, it only displays a blank page.

Do you have any ideas ?

I'm using Vue Rooter by the way

Thank you !

Antoine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

frameworks are generally template transpiler. they don't work like real HTML.

### 1)

here is one way but make sure vue-HTML loaders are in place.

also, you have to use the js/ts files as a mixin in this way though.

```
//AppBar.vue
<template>
 <AppBar/>
</template>

<script>
import AppBar from ./AppBar.html;
import AppBarMixin from .AppBar.js;

export default {
  name : "AppBar",
  mixins:[AppBarMixin],
  components:{
   AppBar
    }
   }
</script>
```

```
//AppBar.html
<div>
    <v-app-bar
      color="#007dbc"
      style="z-index: 1000"
    >
    <v-img
        class="mx-2"
        src="@/assets/dkt_logo.png"
        max-height="40"
        max-width="150"
        contain
      ></v-img>
      <v-toolbar-title style="color: white; font-size: 27px">PCB Sizing</v-toolbar-title>

      <v-spacer></v-spacer>

      <v-btn icon @click="logout" v-if="isLogin">
        <v-icon style="color: white">mdi-logout-variant</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-app-bar>
  </div>
```

```
///AppBar.ts
const AppBarMixin = {
  install(Vue) {
    Vue.mixin({
    data: () => ({
        
    }),
    methods: {
        logout(){
            this.$router.push('/')
        }
    },
    computed:{
        isLogin(){
            return !['Login'].includes(this.$route.name)
        }
     }
    });
  }

export default AppBarMixin;
```

but instead of this way, as a typescript user myself, I suggest the second way down here.

### 2)

but in this way, you have installed the ["vue-class-component"](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component) utility library.

also, you don't need any vue components either. so fewer files.

```
-file.html
-file.ts
-file.css
```

```
///AppBar.html
<div>
    <v-app-bar
      color="#007dbc"
      style="z-index: 1000"
    >
    <v-img
        class="mx-2"
        src="@/assets/dkt_logo.png"
        max-height="40"
        max-width="150"
        contain
      ></v-img>
      <v-toolbar-title style="color: white; font-size: 27px">PCB Sizing</v-toolbar-title>

      <v-spacer></v-spacer>

      <v-btn icon @click="logout" v-if="isLogin">
        <v-icon style="color: white">mdi-logout-variant</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-app-bar>
  </div>
```

```
///AppBar.ts
import Vue from 'vue';
import Component from 'vue-class-component';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './AppBar.html' //link to your HTML file
})


export class AppBar extends Vue {
    name : "AppBar",
    data: () => ({
        
    }),
    methods: {
        logout(){
            this.$router.push('/')
        }
    },
    computed:{
        isLogin(){
            return !['Login'].includes(this.$route.name)
        }
    }
}
```

[here](https://github.com/jsonberry/vue-typescript-examples) is a example vue  project using the second way

Comment: Thank you ! I used the second method to do it !